# Position svg element at click position with transform scale applied

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need to position an svg `path` element at the click position

My example code is as follows

```
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
const offset = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

svg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const width = svg.clientWidth;
    const ratio = viewBox[2] / width;

    const x = (e.pageX - offset.x) * ratio ;
    const y = (e.pageY - offset.y) * ratio;

    const tp = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    tp.setAttribute('fill', 'F7931E');
    tp.setAttribute('stroke', '#000');
    tp.setAttribute('d', 'M37,17v15H14V17z M50,0H0v50h50z');
    tp.setAttribute('transform', `scale(1) translate(${x}, ${y })`);

    svg.appendChild(tp);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7oLokxsh/11/)

As you can see there is a lot to take into account in order to possition the `path` where you click. Now, I would like to scale the `path`

```
 tp.setAttribute('transform', `scale(.3) translate(${x}, ${y})`);
```

This, unfortunately, changes everything; [DEMO with scale = .3](https://jsfiddle.net/7oLokxsh/15/)

So the question is, how can I compute the correct transform values in this case ?

Probably a bit related, as you can see, if scaling is off, the `path` is placed such that the mouse pointer is at the top-left corner. I would like to have it at its center. Any guidinance would be appreciated!

One final note, I'm looking for a solution which is generic, meaning it works for any shape

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of `scale` and `translate`? You may also want to consider `transform-origin`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) However,  the `transform-origin` is harder to implement. Whatever I do, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7oLokxsh/18/) it doesn't place the path at the right place. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Found the solution ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7oLokxsh/20/)) With `transform-origin` you still need to correct for the path dimensions. Thanks a lot for your help!!